Почему данные из массива значений суммируются как строки?
Задача: из массива данных на листе нужно собрать числовые данные по ЮЛ (примерно 10 ЮЛ) и записать их в ячейку на другом листе. Когда пытаюсь достать данные из listDebt[0] и сложить их в логах отображаются 2 числа просто "написанные" друг за другом. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?
Логи:
Информация 1598360015983600

listDebt[0] хранит число 15983600
Код:
function autofillPost(){
  let sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()
  let list = sheet[11].getRange(4,2,sheet[11].getRange("M1").getValue(),1).getValues()
  let listDebt=sheet[11].getRange(4,6,sheet[11].getRange('M1').getValue(),1).getValues()
  let listOwerDebt=sheet[11].getRange(4,8,sheet[11].getRange('M1').getValue(),1).getValues()
  let listPostDebt=sheet[11].getRange(4,11,sheet[11].getRange('M1').getValue(),1).getValues()

  let arrayCountDebt=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
  let arrayCountOwerDebt=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
  let arrayCountPostDebt=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

  var b=listDebt[0]

  Logger.log(b+b)
}


Просто приведите к нужному типу, используя "+" перед строкой или Number(ваше число). Например:
const result = +num[0] + +num[1]
const result = Number(num[0]) + Number(num[1])

Ааа, забыл ответить на Ваш вопрос, конкатенация происходит потому что по всей видимости данные которые Вы получите, приходят в виде строки

Спасибо, это помогло!
